# Is it possible to extend a J Class without creating a new one?

Tags: java, class, netbeans-8, extends

I want to extend the JComponent Class but i don't want to create a new one which extends it.
What i want to do is like:

```
static class JComponent extends JComponent ....
```

For example, i have:

```
    static int a = 0;
```

and when i create a new JComponent

```
    Jbutton button = new Jbutton();
```

The a will become 1 automatically.

Then if i create a other JComponent

```
    JtextField text = new JTextField();
```

The a will become 2 etc, automatically.

**P.S** I know it is probably pretty simple but i dont know what i need to search for.
If this is already answered, please provide link, thanks.

Comment: No, you can't extend a class without creating another class. What are you really trying to achieve? Why do you care about the number of components you create? And why would you name such a variable `a`?

Comment: about the name, it is just a example.
about what i am trying to do is, i have a method which places a component above, below etc a other component.
So i want to have a array with all my components (that would automatically update when i create a new1) and a being the number of each component.
I want that cose currently, when i want to place a component somewhere else, i have to move every other, so by giving every component a number, i could make every component automatically placing itself when i change the position of 1 of them

Comment: I really don't see why you would need to extend anything to do that.

Comment: i just wanted the a++ to becoming automatically instead of manually writing it every time i create a new comp.

Comment: i have a method which is like "Place the X1 Component at the center of the label (X Axis)" then i have a other method which is like "Place X2 10 pixels below X1" so lets say i wanted to change X2 to be above X1, i would need to change the methods for both X's ... and i am doing that with like 10 components (currently).

Comment: It seems you're reinventing layout managers. Don't. Plenty exist already. Again, I don't see anything in what you describe that would be solved by inheritance.

Comment: Well I am trying to assume.You need to extend a Jsomething class to add a method that will alter a by one , right?Then why if you want to extend it  you don't want to make a new one??It's confusing.Tsakirogf@hotmail.com send me if you want we can discuss this in Greek.

Comment: because i dont want to type CustomJButton X = new CustomJButton(); ----- i want to type JButton X = new JButton(); and auto increase `a` that way.
JB said it isnt possible so all cool.... i will just make a new class.